# hPear Mail PHP Error

Tags: php, email, smtp

The following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

ob_start();
include('mplookup.php');
ob_end_clean();
$email = $_POST['emailfrom'];

 require_once "mail/Mail.php";

 $from = "***********************";

 $to = "************************";
 $subject = "Sisi's visit to the UK: Sent using the ERC's Tool";
 $text = $_POST['text'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $footer = '<br><em><strong>Disclaimer: &quot;Any views or opinions presented in this email are solely those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of EG4DEMUK.&nbsp; EG4DEMUK will not accept any liability in respect of defamatory or threatening communication. If you would like to raise a complaint about an email sent using our tool, please contact us at <a href="mailto:ercegypt.uk@ercegypt.org?subject=Email%20Complaint"></a>&quot;.</strong></em><p>-----------------------------------------------------------</p>
The ERC is an organisation that brings together Egyptian citizens and movements abroad, irrespective of their political or ideological affiliations. We share in common a belief in the principles of the January 25th Revolution and oppose all aspects of corruption and dictatorship in Egypt. We believe in constitutional legitimacy and work for the establishment of a civil state that reflects the will of the Egyptian people and their freedom in choosing their government.</p>';
 $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
 $name = $_POST['flname'];

 $body = $text.$name."<br />".$address."<br />".$city."<br />".$postcode."<br />".$footer;

 $host = "****************************************
 $port = "***";
 $username = "************************";
 $password = "**************";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
   'MIME-Version' => "1.0",
   'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n\r\n");
   'Reply-To' => $email,
   "BCC: ****************\r\n";
   "CC: $email\r\n";
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
```

This returns the error:

[Sun Jul 26 21:41:01.402278 2015] [:error] [pid 3246] [client 127.0.0.1:57710] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /var/www/html/smtpmail/form.php on line 35, referer: http://localhost/smtpmail/mplookup.php

Any help is much appreciated.

**This particular error has been solved. However, a new error occurs.**
**New code:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('mplookup.php');
ob_end_clean();
include("mail/Mail.php");
/* mail setup recipients, subject etc */
$recipients = "******************";
$headers["From"] = "ercegypt.uk@ercegypt.org";
$headers["To"] = "********************";
$headers["Subject"] = "Sisi's visit to the UK: Sent using the ERC's Tool";
$email = $_POST['emailfrom'];
$human = $_POST['human'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$footer = '<br><em><strong>Disclaimer: &quot;Any views or opinions presented in this email are solely those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of EG4DEMUK.&nbsp; EG4DEMUK will not accept any liability in respect of defamatory or threatening communication. If you would like to raise a complaint about an email sent using our tool, please contact us at <a href="mailto:ercegypt.uk@ercegypt.org?subject=Email%20Complaint"></a>&quot;.</strong></em><p>-----------------------------------------------------------</p>
The ERC is an organisation that brings together Egyptian citizens and movements abroad, irrespective of their political or ideological affiliations. We share in common a belief in the principles of the January 25th Revolution and oppose all aspects of corruption and dictatorship in Egypt. We believe in constitutional legitimacy and work for the establishment of a civil state that reflects the will of the Egyptian people and their freedom in choosing their government.</p>';
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$name = $_POST['flname'];
$message = $text.$name."<br />".$address."<br />".$city."<br />".$postcode."<br />".$footer;
/* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
$smtpinfo["host"] = "******************************";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "465";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "*******************";
$smtpinfo["password"] = "**************";
/* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
/* Ok send mail */
if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4')
{
    if ($mail_object->send($message,$headers))
     {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent! Thank you for participating in EG4DEMUK\'s campaign.</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, please go back and try again!</p>';
    }
}

?>
```

**New error:**

[Sun Jul 26 22:34:41.064227 2015] [:error] [pid 3240] [client 127.0.0.1:58834] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 3 for Mail_smtp::send(), called in /var/www/html/smtpmail/form.php on line 32 and defined in /var/www/html/smtpmail/mail/Mail/smtp.php on line 245, referer: http://localhost/smtpmail/mplookup.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're got too many closing brackets for the headers array between lines 32 to 39 inc.

Try removing the closing brackets on lines 34 and 36 and adding a closing bracket on line 39.